# Error creating bean Autowiring of fields failed; spring

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I try to user Spring 4 and quartz 2 and java 1.6 in web application deployed in weblogic 10.3.6

I faces the below exception when try to deploy:

```
>     <ContextLoader> <initWebApplicationContext> Context initialization failed
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'startup': Autowiring of fields failed; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Could not autowire field: private
> com.xxx.payment.scheduler.manager.SchedulerManager
> com.xxx.payment.scheduler.Startup.schedulerManager; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'schedulerBean' defined in class path resource
> [META-INF/spring/applicationContext-scheduler.xml]: Instantiation of
> bean failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
> instantiate bean class
> [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean]:
> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:243)
```

the application context:

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.payment" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/WCMAppsDS" />

    <bean id="schedulerBean"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">

        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/META-INF/quartz.properties" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="schedulerName" value="quartzScheduler" />
        <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="false" />
        <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
        <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />
    </bean>
```

I need help for solve this problem

Comment: Is the `SchedulerFactoryBean` on your classpath?

Comment: yes, SchedulerFactoryBean in classpath